# Changing editing mode in Sublime Text 3: toggle multiple settings with a command or macro

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I would like to introduce a new editing mode in ST3 similar to *Distraction-Free Mode*, without modifying its settings.

I can achieve the desired result by setting a number of settings, namely `draw_centered=true`, `word_wrap=true`, `wrap_width=90`, etc.

However, I would like to be able to **toggle** all these settings at once (with a shortcut or from the command palette). When I toggle out of this mode, the settings should be restored to whatever they were before (not necessarily the default settings).

Here is how I would set the settings in a macro:

```
[
    { "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "word_wrap", "value": true } },
    { "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "wrap_width", "value": 80 } },
    { "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "draw_centered", "value": true } },
    { "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "line_padding_top", "value": 1 } },
    { "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "line_padding_bottom", "value": 1 } }
]
```

This, however, sets the settings to a particular value. I would like to be able to toggle them back to a previous state.

How would I do that, in a macro or as a command?

Comment: You'll need a plugin for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Demo]

---

Save the following script @:
`/Packages/Toggle Custom View/toggle_custom_view.py`

```python
import sublime, sublime_plugin

STORED_SETTINGS = {}

class toggle_custom_view( sublime_plugin.TextCommand ):
    def run( self, edit ):

        view     = self.view
        settings = view.settings()

        if settings.get( "is_widget" ):
            return

        if view.file_name():
            viewID = view.file_name()
        else:
            viewID = str( view )

        global STORED_SETTINGS
        if not viewID in STORED_SETTINGS:
            STORED_SETTINGS[ viewID ] = {
                "custom_view_enabled": True,
                "word_wrap":           settings.get( "word_wrap"           ),
                "wrap_width":          settings.get( "wrap_width"          ),
                "draw_centered":       settings.get( "draw_centered"       ),
                "line_padding_top":    settings.get( "line_padding_top"    ),
                "line_padding_bottom": settings.get( "line_padding_bottom" ),
            }
        storedSettings = STORED_SETTINGS[ viewID ]

        if storedSettings[ "custom_view_enabled" ]:
            settings.set( "word_wrap",           True )
            settings.set( "wrap_width",          80   )
            settings.set( "draw_centered",       True )
            settings.set( "line_padding_top",    1    )
            settings.set( "line_padding_bottom", 1    )

        else:
            settings.set( "word_wrap",           storedSettings[ "word_wrap"           ] )
            settings.set( "wrap_width",          storedSettings[ "wrap_width"          ] )
            settings.set( "draw_centered",       storedSettings[ "draw_centered"       ] )
            settings.set( "line_padding_top",    storedSettings[ "line_padding_top"    ] )
            settings.set( "line_padding_bottom", storedSettings[ "line_padding_bottom" ] )

        storedSettings[ "custom_view_enabled" ] = not storedSettings[ "custom_view_enabled" ]
```

---

To execute via `Command Palette > Toggle Custom View`, save the following code @:
`/Packages/Toggle Custom View/Default.sublime-commands`

```json
[
    {
        "caption": "Toggle Custom View",
        "command": "toggle_custom_view",
    },
]
```

---

To execute via <kbd>Ctrl + Super + Alt + V</kbd>, save the following code @:
`/Packages/Toggle Custom View/Default.sublime-keymap`

```json
[
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+super+alt+v"],
        "command": "toggle_custom_view",
    },
]
```